# Checkbox burger menu covering body content

Tags: html, css, menu, cover

I'm having a problem with my checkbox burger menu dropdown is covering content when clicked. It may also look like the menu itself isn't "connected" to the navbar when clicked.

I have tried changing position to absolute but that creates a hidden problem I can't solve.

My first stackoverflow, and one of my first projects. Thanks for patience and help :)

https://jsfiddle.net/ow82jhbm/1/

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:1111px) {
  #navtekst {
    display: none;
  }
}

#sidebarMenu {
  height: auto;
  /*change here related your menu height*/
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translateY(-171px);
  /*change here related your menu height*/
}

.main-content-wrapper a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0.5px solid white;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#sidebarMenu {
  transform: translatey(0);
  top: 50px/*change here related your top menu height*/
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  display: none
}


/*Whole spinner*/

.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}


/*Each line in spinner*/

.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}


/*Spinner rotation*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1111px) {
  .sidebarIconToggle {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark text-white">
  <!--Brand/logo-->
  <a class="navbar-brand">
    <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="TradeLeague-1 (7).png" />
  </a>

  <!--Links-->
  <ul class="navbar-nav" [class.is-open]="isMenuOpen" style="font-size:18px" id="navtekst">
    <!--Homepage-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
    <!--Create company-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/createcompany">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Create Company</a>
    </li>
    <!--Company list-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/companies">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Companies</a>
    </li>
    <!--Leaderboard-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/leaderboard">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Leaderboard</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--Creating a new list aligned to the right-->
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="font-size:18px" id="navtekst">
    <!--Log-in Page-->
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Sign-in</a>
    </li>
    <!--Profilepage-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/profile"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>    Profile</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu ml-auto" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
        <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
        <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
        <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    </label>

  <div id="sidebarMenu" class="bg-dark">
    <div class="main-content-wrapper">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/createuser">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Create User</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/createcompany">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Create Company</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/companies">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Companies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/leaderboard">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Leaderboard</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Sign in</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/profile">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<br/>

<!--HTML EXAMPLE*/-->

<div class="container bg-dark card text-white" style="text-align: center; width: 65%">
  <br />
  <!--Header-->
  <h1><u>Create User</u></h1>
  <br />
  <!--Form for creating new user-->
  <form [formGroup]="skjema" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="username" />
      <p class="alert alert-warning" [hidden]="skjema.controls.username.valid || (skjema.controls.username.pristine && !submitted)">
        Username er obligatorisk.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="password" />
      <p class="alert alert-warning" [hidden]="skjema.controls.password.valid || (skjema.controls.password.pristine && !submitted)">
        Password er obligatorisk.
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--Sends company to script with function createUser() when confirm button is pressed-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" style="margin-right:15px" [disabled]="!skjema.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Registrer</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/">Tilbake</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this is done using JS and targets the same menu instead of using two.

With your current structure, you can make this work by first changing `#sidebarMenu` to `position: absolute;`. Then target `input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#sidebarMenu` and use `top: 100%;` to make sure your menu is appearing directly below the navbar. Make sure you remove the `translateY` value in those styles.

Next, to get the dropdown menu to push down the other content you will have to use `position: relative;` on `input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#sidebarMenu`. This enables the menu to push down and extend the actual navbar height. I used `flex` to re-configure the alignment of your nav on mobile.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:1111px) {
  #navtekst {
    display: none;
  }
}

#sidebarMenu {
  height: auto;
  /*change here related your menu height*/
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translateY(-171px);
  /*change here related your menu height*/
}

.main-content-wrapper a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0.5px solid white;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebarMenuInner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#sidebarMenu {
  transform: translatey(0);
  position: relative;
  top: 100%/*change here related your top menu height*/
  ;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.sidebarIconToggle {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  display: none
}


/*Whole spinner*/

.spinner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}


/*Each line in spinner*/

.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}


/*Spinner rotation*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.horizontal {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-1 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.sidebarIconToggle>.diagonal.part-2 {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1111px) {
  .sidebarIconToggle {
    display: block
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-flow: column !important;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    width: 99%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1111px) {
  #sidebarMenu {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark text-white">
  <!--Brand/logo-->
  <a class="navbar-brand">
    <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="TradeLeague-1 (7).png" />
  </a>

  <!--Links-->
  <ul class="navbar-nav" [class.is-open]="isMenuOpen" style="font-size:18px" id="navtekst">
    <!--Homepage-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
    <!--Create company-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/createcompany">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Create Company</a>
    </li>
    <!--Company list-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/companies">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Companies</a>
    </li>
    <!--Leaderboard-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/leaderboard">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Leaderboard</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--Creating a new list aligned to the right-->
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="font-size:18px" id="navtekst">
    <!--Log-in Page-->
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Sign-in</a>
    </li>
    <!--Profilepage-->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <!--Routering and displaying active page-->
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/profile"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>    Profile</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu ml-auto" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
        <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
        <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
        <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    </label>

  <div id="sidebarMenu" class="bg-dark">
    <div class="main-content-wrapper">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/createuser">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Create User</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/createcompany">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Create Company</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/companies">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Companies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/leaderboard">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Leaderboard</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Sign in</a>
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/profile">  &nbsp;&nbsp;Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<br/>

<!--HTML EXAMPLE*/-->

<div class="container bg-dark card text-white" style="text-align: center; width: 65%">
  <br />
  <!--Header-->
  <h1><u>Create User</u></h1>
  <br />
  <!--Form for creating new user-->
  <form [formGroup]="skjema" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="username" />
      <p class="alert alert-warning" [hidden]="skjema.controls.username.valid || (skjema.controls.username.pristine && !submitted)">
        Username er obligatorisk.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="password" />
      <p class="alert alert-warning" [hidden]="skjema.controls.password.valid || (skjema.controls.password.pristine && !submitted)">
        Password er obligatorisk.
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--Sends company to script with function createUser() when confirm button is pressed-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" style="margin-right:15px" [disabled]="!skjema.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Registrer</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/">Tilbake</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! When I resize (wider) the window while the sidebar-icon is toggled the dropdown-menu moves next to the original navbar. Do you know a solution?

Comment: @KungK Yup, add a `min-width` media query and tell `#sidebarMenu` to `display: none;` above `1111px`. See changes above.